# Sonata Admin - access the mailer

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to create a custom batch action using `Sonata Admin Bundle`, that sends an email.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to access swiftmailer. I have the following:

```
public function batchActionSend(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery)
{
   if($this->admin->isGranted('EDIT')=== false) {
       throw new AccessDeniedException();
   }

   $request = $this->get('request');
   $modelManager = $this->admin->getModelManager();

   $selectedModels = $selectedModelQuery->execute();

   try {
       foreach ($selectedModels as $selectedModel) {
           // send the email here?
           $selectedModel->send();
           $modelManager->update($selectedModel);
       }
   } catch (\Exception $e) {
       $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('sonata_flash_error', $e->getMessage());

       return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl('list',$this->admin->getFilterParameters()));
   }

   $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('sonata_flash_success',  sprintf('The selected requests have been sent'));

   return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl('list',$this->admin->getFilterParameters()));
```

In my entity I have the following:

```
public function send()
{
   // send email here?
}
```

What is the best way to access the mailer? via the Admin Class or via the Entity or via a service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Swift_Message::newInstance()`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/email/email.html)

```
public function send()
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
        ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'HelloBundle:Hello:email.txt.twig',
                array('name' => $name)
            )
        )
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

}
```